# iOS: Alert is only triggered once SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have an app that required some alerts. I have implemented the alert trigger with observableObject so that it can be triggered from the my coordinator class. The problem I am having is that the first trigger work and the alert shows. But after the first time no matter how many times I trigger the button the alert does not show.
The view has a webview (UIRepresentable) where when a button is pressed on the webpage the JS triggers the alert in the coordinator class

Relevant parts of code below

MainView with showAlerts class:

```
import SwiftUI
import WebKit

struct MainContentView: View {

    
    @ObservedObject public var viewAlertsInstance = ShowAlerts()
    
    
    var body: some View {

        ZStack {

       SubscriptionViewController(showAlert: viewAlertsInstance)

        }
        .alert(isPresented: $viewAlertsInstance.showAlert) {
            Alert(
                title: Text("Important message"),
                message: Text("Something"),
                dismissButton: .default(Text("Got it!"))
            )
        }


    }

}

class ShowAlerts: ObservableObject {
    @Published var showAlert:Bool = false
    
    func displayAlert() {
        self.showAlert.toggle()
        print(showAlert)
    }
    
}
```

SubscriptionView including the coordinator:

```
import SwiftUI
import WebKit

struct SubscriptionViewController: UIViewRepresentable {
    @StateObject var showAlert: ShowAlerts
    
    
    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<SubscriptionViewController>) -> WKWebView {

        
        let view = WKWebView()
        view.navigationDelegate = context.coordinator
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let url = URL(string:"https")!
            let request = URLRequest(url: url)
            
            view.load(request)
        }
        
        context.coordinator.webView = view
        return view
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<SubscriptionViewController>) {
        
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> CoordinatorSubscription {
        CoordinatorSubscription(self, showAlert: self.showAlert)
    }
    
    typealias UIViewType = WKWebView
}


class CoordinatorSubscription: NSObject, WKNavigationDelegate, WKScriptMessageHandler{
    
    var control: SubscriptionViewController
    var showAlert: ShowAlerts
    
    var webView : WKWebView?

    init(_ control: SubscriptionViewController, showAlert: ShowAlerts) {
        self.control = control
        self.showAlert = showAlert
    }
    
    func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
        processReturnedJS(body: message.body as! String)
    }
    

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        
    }
    
    func processReturnedJS(body: String) {
        

            //Here should toggle the alert
            showAlert.displayAlert()
    }
}
```

In the processReturnedJS function the showAlert.displayAlert() should show the alert every-time the JS is received

Would appreciate any help

Thanks

Comment: You are using `@StateObject` and`@ObservedObject` incorrectly `@StateObject` is for initializing and `@ObservedObject` is initialized with an `init` parameter. Just swap them. Also, remove `var showAlert: ShowAlerts` from the coordinator and access like this `control.showAlert.displayAlert()`

Comment: Awesome I posted it as an answer. If you don’t mind please accept and upvote if you would like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swap your

```
@StateObject and @ObservedObject wrappers
```

StateObject is for initializing and ObservedObject takes its initial value as a parameter in the initializer per apple documentation.

Then remove

```
 var showAlert: ShowAlerts
```

In your coordinator and access the variable like this

```
 control.showAlert.displayAlert()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you flipped the use of `@ObservedObject` and `@StateObject`.

When you find yourself creating a default or a starting value for your object, like you're doing in `MainContentView`, use `@StateObject`.

When you are creating your object elsewhere up the view hierarchy and just want your view to observe the object, use `@ObservedObject`.